# Ignore Keyboard Input During Sleep in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

A similar question for Python was asked.

[How to ignore user input during sleep in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037502/how-to-ignore-user-input-during-sleep-in-python-3)

How would I do that in C++? I am using this sleep command, and would prefer to keep using it.

```
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(4));
```

However, it still will collect user input, which causes the user to miss important text they skip over. How can I prevent this?

Input as in Keyboard input using:

```
_getch();
```

This is a console application.

```
cout << "Wait 4 Seconds";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(4));
cout << "More text here!";
cout << "\n Press any key to go on";
_getch();
```

**AFTER ANSWER EDIT**
Final Code would look like this:

```
cout << "Wait 4 Seconds";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(4));
while (_kbhit())
{_getch();}
cout << "More text here!";
cout << "\n Press any key to go on";
_getch();
```

Comment: User input from what? Keyboard? Mouse? GUI? Miss important text how?

Comment: What input code are you using?  have you tried?  single char at a time?  or getline?  These should make a difference.

Comment: Just flush the input immediately after the call to `sleep_for` returns.

Comment: If your app is all one thread, then when that thread sleeps, nothing else will take place.

Comment: I don't know how POSIX-compliant MS Windows's POSIX emulation is. On a POSIX-compliant platform, this is done by temporary setting standard input to non-blocking, draining all input (in your case, via your _getch() function), then resetting standard input to blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sleeping, you can...

```
while (kbhit())
    getch();
```

This sees if there's input waiting, and if so call `getch()` to discard a character.  Rinse and repeat.

God knows how MS name their functions, but if you can't find `kbhit()` try [`_kbhit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx) from `<conio.h>`.

Comment: It was _kbhit! Thanks

Comment: The POSIX name getch is deprecated. So Microsoft use the ISO C and C++ conformant name _getch instead.  Gory details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814975/getch-is-deprecated